# Change PayPal button amount input value to user's selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, paypal

I've seen an example that does this but I get "undefined" every time I try to access the values.  I want the user to be able to enter an amount and then set that amount within the input value.  The HTML looks like this:

```
echo '<div class="article">
    <input size="1" class="quantity" value="1"/>
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail...">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$item.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$price.'">
    //so on...
    </form>
</div>';
```

There are several item on the page, each in a `div` class article.  With jQuery I'm trying to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".quantity").change(function() {
        alert($(this).siblings('form input[name="item_name"]').val());
        //$(this).siblings('form input[name="quantity"]').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

I keep getting "undefined"...when I tested another input field within the article `div`, I could get the `val()` and change it.  What am I doing wrong here?

SOLUTION:

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389552/paypal-html-form-with-select-drop-menu) helped me...had to get rid of JS, unhide the inputs and just let the user fill out the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not simple and smart without js? just remove the `hidden` type from your quantity input field and change it to `text`

```
echo '<div class="article">
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail...">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$item.'">
            <input name="quantity" class="quantity" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$price.'">

            //so on...
        </form>
     </div>';
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after seeing the example.  I couldn't let go of JS for a while, figuring it was the only way.

Answer (score 0):

[I have crafted a fiddle for you below just click this link.](http://jsfiddle.net/B69YM/)

```
<div class="article">
    <input size="1" class="quantity" value="1" />
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail..." />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$item.'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$price.'" />
    </form>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".quantity").change(function() {
        console.log($(this).next().find("input[name='item_name']").val());
        //$(this).siblings('form input[name="quantity"]').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```